# Force aws lambda to fail in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: aws-lambda, bitbucket-pipelines

I am triggering aws lambda from a bitbucket pipeline and I need that step to fail when an error occurs in the lambda function. Currently, the response contains statusCode: 200 with functionError: Unhandled and the step succeeds. Does anyone know how can I cause this step to fail on functionError?

In order to invoke lambda, I use the below script in the bitbucket.yml file

`aws lambda invoke --function-name my-function --payload '{ "name": "Bob" }' response.json`

I had tried using the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57284329/boto3-python-lambda-customise-return-error) which was to raise an exception on error but that didn't fail the bitbucket pipeline.

Comment: Can you document in your question which approach you tried out?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Awesome! This is very useful. Could you also share the code of your Lambda? I suspect that this will greatly help to answer your question!